# Rust decode nokhwa::Buffer into a pre-allocated buffer

Tags: rust, video, decoding

I am trying to decode a [`Buffer`](https://docs.rs/nokhwa/latest/nokhwa/struct.Buffer.html) type from the [nokhwa](https://docs.rs/nokhwa/latest/nokhwa/) crate into a pre-allocated `Vec<u8>` using the [`decode_image_to_buffer`](https://docs.rs/nokhwa/latest/nokhwa/struct.Buffer.html#method.decode_image_to_buffer) method. This is my code so far:

```
use nokhwa::{
    pixel_format::{RgbAFormat},
    utils::{
        yuyv422_predicted_size,
    },
    Buffer,
};

// buffer is an instance of the nokhwa::Buffer struct
// frame_buffer is a Vec<u8>

frame_buffer.resize(yuyv422_predicted_size(buffer.buffer().len(), true), 0);
buffer.decode_image_to_buffer::<RgbAFormat>(&mut frame_buffer)
    .unwrap();
```

This code works perfectly on linux. But when I try to run in on windows, I get the following error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: 
ProcessFrameError { src: MJPEG, destination: "RGB888",
error: "Bad decoded buffer size" }', src\main.rs:86:75
```

I am not sure, but I think that the error comes from the [`mozjpeg`](https://docs.rs/mozjpeg/latest/mozjpeg/) crate. Which is used by `nokhwa` to implement the `decode_image_to_buffer` method. To be more specific, I think the error comes from [this call](https://github.com/ImageOptim/mozjpeg-rust/blob/1a786819990bb393acb0416777e2584f73aa8369/src/decompress.rs#L399) to the `jpeg_start_decompress` function.

I don't know if it's my code or a bug in the dependencies I am using. I reached a dead end. Please help.

Comment: I think these bits of code are relevant: https://docs.rs/nokhwa-core/0.1.0/src/nokhwa_core/types.rs.html#1568-1574, https://github.com/ImageOptim/mozjpeg-rust/blob/1a786819990bb393acb0416777e2584f73aa8369/src/decompress.rs#L411-L415, https://github.com/l1npengtul/nokhwa/blob/3f570ee0e5b72ec7957d8bc02fb83aae2392ff07/nokhwa-core/src/types.rs#L1313-L1319

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I fixed the problem. Turns out `nokhwa`'s `yuyv422_predicted_size` function does not return the correct value for the buffer size. To fix the problem, I added [`mozjpeg`](https://docs.rs/mozjpeg/latest/mozjpeg/) as a dependency in my `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
mozjpeg = "0.9.4"
```

And used it directly to perform the decoding.

```
use mozjpeg::{Decompress, ColorSpace};

let decompress = Decompress::new_mem(buffer.buffer()).unwrap();

let mut decompress = decompress.rgba().unwrap();

let num_components = match decompress.color_space() {
    ColorSpace::JCS_UNKNOWN => 0,
    ColorSpace::JCS_GRAYSCALE => 1,
    ColorSpace::JCS_RGB => 3,
    ColorSpace::JCS_YCbCr => 3,
    ColorSpace::JCS_CMYK => 4,
    ColorSpace::JCS_YCCK => 4,
    ColorSpace::JCS_EXT_RGB => 3,
    ColorSpace::JCS_EXT_RGBX => 4,
    ColorSpace::JCS_EXT_BGR => 3,
    ColorSpace::JCS_EXT_BGRX => 4,
    ColorSpace::JCS_EXT_XBGR => 4,
    ColorSpace::JCS_EXT_XRGB => 4,
    ColorSpace::JCS_EXT_RGBA => 4,
    ColorSpace::JCS_EXT_BGRA => 4,
    ColorSpace::JCS_EXT_ABGR => 4,
    ColorSpace::JCS_EXT_ARGB => 4,
    ColorSpace::JCS_RGB565 => 3,
};

frame_buffer.resize(decompress.width() * decompress.height() * num_components, 0);

decompress.read_scanlines_flat_into(&mut frame_buffer);
```

EDIT:

Even easier. The `Decompress` struct has a `min_flat_buffer_size` method. Which can be used to calculate the desired buffer size. i.e.

```
use mozjpeg::{Decompress};

let decompress = Decompress::new_mem(buffer.buffer()).unwrap();

let mut decompress = decompress.rgba().unwrap();

frame_buffer.resize(decompress.min_flat_buffer_size(), 0);

decompress.read_scanlines_flat_into(&mut frame_buffer);
```